# What is the purpose of the action=reboot parameter for the command Sc failure

Tags: windows-services

So I know that the following command would cause the windows service to restart after 30 seconds.

```
sc failure %SERVICE_NAME% reset= 60 actions= restart/30000
```

In this article here: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc742019.aspx#BKMK_examples

They have the following example command:

```
sc failure myservice reset= 3600 reboot= "MyService crashed -- rebooting machine" command= "%windir%\MyServiceRecovery.exe" actions= restart/5000/run/10000/reboot/60000
```

Can anyone please explain what the reboot action does?

My guess is that it first broadcasts the message in specified in the reboot parameter and then runs the executable in the command parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Typing `sc failure /?` brings up the built-in help:

```
DESCRIPTION:
        Changes the actions upon failure
USAGE:
        sc <server> failure [service name] <option1> <option2>...

OPTIONS:
        reset=   <Length of period of no failures (in seconds)
                  after which to reset the failure count to 0 (may be INFINITE)>

                  (Must be used in conjunction with actions= )
        reboot=  <Message broadcast before rebooting on failure>
        command= <Command line to be run on failure>
        actions= <Failure actions and their delay time (in milliseconds),
                  separated by / (forward slash) -- e.g., run/5000/reboot/800
                  Valid actions are <run|restart|reboot> >
                  (Must be used in conjunction with the reset= option)
```

As you suspected, the `reboot` *option* specifies a message to be broadcast on reboot.

The `reboot` *action* in `actions` causes the machine to reboot.